# Will a laptop run faster at a lower screen resolution than at its native resolution of the screen?

Tags: laptop, performance, resolution

I use my low performance laptop (n5000, 4 GB RAM) at an 1368x768 resolution instead of the screen full HD native resolution of 1920x1080, as I thought it must be faster using this screen resolution. But now I have doubts about the validity of this idea, as maybe everything should be somehow downscaled. What could be the truth?

Answer (score 1):

Lowering the resolution will only help if it actually takes effort to draw on the screen.

This essentially means that only if the entire screen is updated multiple times in quick succession, it will matter if the resolution is lower. As a result, the quality what's on the screen is also lowered. For normal desktop usage, going with the native resolution is always the way to go unless you have eye sight problems and need things larger but not use the DPI setting to do so.

When it comes to using a lower resolution, video playback may get a performance increase, but it also may not. The real place where a lower resolution will help is 3D graphics, such as full-screen games.

So, for normal desktop usage, its recommended to use the 1080p resolution. For gaming going for a lower resolution may be better if its a demanding game.

Answer (score -1):

I mean it should increase,  but if the difference is not noticeable  its your RAM   try upgrading your RAM      4 GB RAM is not enough for any PC to run fast
so I suggest upgrading your RAM to 8GB, if you want to see some noticeable results

Comment: Not upgradable, soldered RAM module, ACER SWIFT SF114-32